# Gitlab ci job - spring boot integration tests fail to load application context

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, integration-testing

I'm trying to run a job to execute the tests of a spring boot app in our ci pipelines, I'm new to working with gitlab ci pipelines but i found a [job configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/unit_test_report_examples.html#maven) to do that. The project contains both unit and integration tests. In my case, i changed the **mvn** command to **./mvnw** to be able to execute the **verify** command. My job looks like this:

```
verification:
  stage: verify
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - chmod +x mvnw
    - ./mvnw verify
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
```

The unit tests are executed **without any problems**, but the integration tests which try to load the application context fail due to an error thrown because of the application.properties values of some properties that are set up to use environment variables, the error is like the following:

```
> SampleServiceTest.givenIdDeleteObject » IllegalState Failed to load
> ApplicationContext.......

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
> placeholder 'SHOW_SQL' in value "${SHOW_SQL}"
```

in the project's application.properties, there is a property set:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=${SHOW_SQL}
```

the already existing jobs **which compile and deploy** the app **don't have any errors**, and **they pass** every time the pipeline runs.

Is there anything i'm missing regarding the execution of the integration tests in this new job?